# What is this crosshair and left arrow sign for Adobe Illustrator do?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I'm not sure what keys I hit, but my **rectangle tool** has a crosshair and a left arrow attached to a vertical bar. When I draw rectangles, they are drawn at a skew and not aligned to a default XY axis.

Anyone know how I got it turned on? What it's purpose is, and more importantly, how to turn it off without restarting?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the icon that appears when you have a perspective grid turned on, but it seems odd that you wouldn't know that the grid was there. In any event, try going to `View > Perspective Grid > Hide Grid` (if it's turned on) or hit `Command-Shift-i`.

Comment: thanks, @chris, appreciate the help... I was only drawing in a small area so didn't see the perspective shift. appreciate it! (and yes, odd that no grid was showing at all)